# If $x>y$, is $|x+y|$ or $|x-y|$ bigger, or neither?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value, number-comparison

**Question:** If $x>y$, is $|x+y|$ or $|x-y|$ bigger, or neither?

I got this question wrong on a GRE practice test, and now I know the correct answer, but I am curious what your thought process is for solving it efficiently.

Edit: This is the full problem as given in the GRE. Problems like this as given in the GRE always have 4 possible solutions: 1) |x+y| is bigger, 2) |x-y| is bigger, 3) |x+y|=|x-y|, or 4) it is not possible to determine.

Comment: Either one can be bigger. Are you maybe also given that $y>0$?

Comment: @Mathematician42-Yeah got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends.

If $x=2$ and $y=1$, then $|x+y|=3 > 1=|x-y|$.

If $x=2$ and $y=-5$, then $|x+y|=3 <7= |x-y|$.

*Addendum:* And of course if $x=2$ and $y=0$, then $|x+y|=|x-y|$ (as *Love invariants* noted in a comment)

Answer (score 2):

For $x=1$ and $y=-1$ we have $$|x+y|<|x-y|.$$

For $x=2$ and $y=1$ we have $$|x+y|>|x-y|.$$

Answer (score 2):

Both quantities are non-negative, so $>$ orders them the same way it does their squares, which are $x^2+y^2+2xy,\,x^2+y^2-2xy$. Therefore, $|x+y|>|x-y|$ iff $xy>0$, i.e. $x,\,y$ are both positive or both negative.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram below shows the plots of $y = x$ and $y = -x$.

[image]

Then $|x+y|$ is the [taxicab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) ($L_1$) distance of a point $(x, y)$ from the red line, while $|x-y|$ is the taxicab distance of that same point from the blue line.

(Note that those taxicab distances are equal to $\sqrt{2}$ times the [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) ($L_2$) distances.)

Therefore, either quantity can be greater.  They are equal along the axes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y=x-t, t>0$$
Then $$|x+y|=|2x-t|$$
$$|x-y|=|t|$$

Observe what happens as we vary our variables.

If $x<0$, one can immediately see that $$|x+y|>|x-y|$$

On the contrary, if $t>x$ while $x>0$, we can establish that:
$$0<|2x-t|<|t|$$ and hence $$|x+y|<|x+y|$$
This occurs when $y<0$.